# Creating Team with Microsoft.Graph dotnet SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

With the [msgraph-sdk-dotnet](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) I create a unified group.

```
var newGroup = await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(new Group
{
    GroupTypes = new List<string> { "Unified" },
    DisplayName = name,
    Description = description,
    MailEnabled = true,
    SecurityEnabled = false,
    Visibility = "Private",
});
```

Next I want to add a Team to it. The docs provide me with the HTTP request to [create a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0) (`PUT /groups/{id}/team`), but I would rather continue using the statically typed SDK.

What is the easiest way to use the SDK in order to create a Team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll add a team like this:

`graphClient.Groups[groupPage[8].Id].Team.Request().PutAsync(team)`

This will be available in the next release.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/pull/352

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Looking forward to it.